# Stuck on Array PHP - only uses last value in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following, 
when the below code process', it gives me a list of ID's etc and Description and Subject. Now since there is a form i put within the loop, when i go to click on "View" button which then display only that specific "Ticket" the issue is, it always displays the same ticket. the last one in the array. why?

```
foreach ($results['results'] as $item) {
  echo 'Ticket ID # '. $item['id'] . ' Subject: '. $item['subject'] .'<br/>';
  echo 'Description : '. $item['description'] .'<br/>';
  echo "<form action=\"view.php\" method=\"post\">";
  echo '<input type="text" name="TicketID" value="'. $item['id'] .'"/>';
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"View\" value=\"View\" />";

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What does var_dump($results['results']); show?

Comment: It shows the array in json_decoded form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not close the `<form>` tag - simply add between the last `<input>` element and the `<br>` elements an `echo '</form>';` line.

Comment: thank you . i think sometimes u just have to step away.. it took me all day =|